# WCF: auto generate data contract classes?

Tags: wcf

I'm using subsonic o/rm to generate my data classes. But the active record and active list classes it generates don't work over WCF. I have to manually write the data contract classes, and this is fairly tedious work for all the properties. Is there any way to automatically generate data contract classes for WCF services? Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool could give you a hand...